Extract results from networkd3 sankey diagram
I'm new here and this is the second time I'm posting this because the previous post was deleted, I don't know what the issue was, would be great if you could state the reason before deleting the post.
So I'm trying again...
This question could be quite basic as I'm just starting to use networkd3, so excuse me for that. I tried looking online for help but unfortunately couldn't find anything. I was wondering if there is any specific way to extract the results of a networkd3 plot.
I'm trying to extract the order of the resulting nodes of the sankey plot in order to use it as an input to other plots but unable to figure out how to extract this information.
I understand that by using iterations=0 I can manually order the nodes but I want to get the ordered nodes so it looks more clean and easier to interpret.
Edit: Including a basic code I found on the internet and modified slightly for reference.
# Library
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)
 
# A connection data frame is a list of flows with intensity for each flow
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("A","A", "B", "C", "C", "E"), 
  target=c("1","3", "3", "3", "2", "1"), 
  value=c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
  )
 
# From these flows we need to create a node data frame: it lists every entities involved in the flow
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), 
  as.character(links$target)) %>% unique()
)
 
# With networkD3, connection must be provided using id, not using real name like in the links dataframe.. So we need to reformat it.
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1
 
# Make the Network
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
              sinksRight=FALSE)

I would like to know if there is a possibility if one could extract the order of the target nodes from the sankey plot.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry your previous question was closed. It might have been closed, because you're not including any code. May you share a small code example of your Sankey diagram? Be specific about what you mean by "results" and "ordered nodes". Sharing a [mcve] will help massively

"Including a basic code I found on the internet for reference." - please include your code, not someone else's "basic code"

The order of the nodes is determined by the data (especially if you use iterations = 0), so couldn't you simply look at the data you already have before putting it in to networkD3::sankeyNetwork()? Otherwise, to get an appropriate answer, I think you would need to be more specific about what you mean by "order" since it's a 2-dimensional plot.

@CJYetman thank you for your response. To be more specific for my question, after producing the sankey plot I would like to extract the order of the target nodes because they are rearranged to produce better looking plot with the links. Why I don't want to use iterations = 0 is because I have to produce a lot of plots and to order it manually I would need a lot of time. For example, in the code I posted above the target nodes are ordered 1, 3 and 2 in the sankey plot and I want to somehow extract that information if it's possible?

Getting JavaScript to send a value back to R is not easy, but the shiny package can do this. So you could add some JavaScript to grab the information you want using htmlwidgets::onRender(), and send it back through shiny with something like this...
# Library
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

# A connection data frame is a list of flows with intensity for each flow
links <- data.frame(
  source=c("A","A", "B", "C", "C", "E"), 
  target=c("1","3", "3", "3", "2", "1"), 
  value=c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)

# From these flows we need to create a node data frame: it lists every entities involved in the flow
nodes <- data.frame(
  name=c(as.character(links$source), 
         as.character(links$target)) %>% unique()
)

# With networkD3, connection must be provided using id, not using real name like in the links dataframe.. So we need to reformat it.
links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1 
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

# Make the Network
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                   Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name", 
                   sinksRight=FALSE)


widget <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  p,
  '
  function(el, x) {
    let sankey = this.sankey;
    let x_of_last_col = Math.max(...sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x));
    var nodes_in_last_col = sankey.nodes().filter(d => d.x == x_of_last_col);
    nodes_in_last_col = nodes_in_last_col.sort((a,b) => a.y > b.y);
    let json_output = JSON.stringify(nodes_in_last_col.map(d => [d.name, d.y]));
    Shiny.setInputValue("x", json_output);
  }
  '
)

node_order <- shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = shiny::bootstrapPage(shiny::textInput("x", "x"), sankeyNetworkOutput("plot")),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderSankeyNetwork({widget});
    shiny::observeEvent(input$x, { shiny::stopApp(input$x) }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  }
))

jsonlite::fromJSON(node_order)
#>      [,1] [,2]              
#> [1,] "1"  "9.99999999999999"
#> [2,] "3"  "173.571428571429"
#> [3,] "2"  "429.285714285714"


Thank you for adding an answer. I tried to run this but it's just stuck on connecting to the shiny server I guess which says 'Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4068' and never goes any further. Anything I'm doing wrong?

No idea. I am not a Shiny expert at all. Maybe you modified the code? Or put in different data?

I initially tried running with my code but later I tried using your code without any modifications and its still the same. Stuck on the node_order part saying 'Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4068'

Maybe update your R packages to the latest versions (and R and RStudio).
